# Do all YouTube videos have captions?

Tags: youtube

The questions only concerns the following languages:

> English, Dutch, French, German,
>   Italian, Japanese, Korean, Portuguese, Russian, Spanish

After reading [YouTube's official documentation](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6373554?hl=en), it would appear that all videos have automatically generated subtitles. However, for example [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhAJV5D353w) doesn't have captions of any kind.

> Review, edit, or unpublish automatic captions
>
> **If automatic captions are available, they'll automatically be
>   published on the video**. Automatic captions may not be ready at the
>   time that you upload a video. Processing time depends on the
>   complexity of the video's audio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sort of answered your own question. **IF** YouTube can generate captions for a video, you'll see them. If they can't, there won't be any automatic captions. Also, if the channel owner doesn't want automatic captions on the video, they can remove them from view.

Comment: "if the channel owner doesn't want automatic captions on the video, they can remove them from view.", is that so? In what situations YT can't generate subtitles?

Comment: I request a source.

Comment: *"if the channel owner doesn't want automatic captions on the video, they can remove them from view.", is that so?* yes, video manager → subtitles/CC → select the automatic capton → unpublish. *In what situations YT can't generate subtitles* if it can't understand the speech. *I request a source* original research.

Answer (score 3):

YouTube will add auto-generated captions if they can. I think that is their official policy because they support accessibility (for hearing impaired and deaf persons in this case, of course).

You have however (currently) to specify the video language for this to work.

Comment: I request a source.

Comment: @user598527 Source for what?

Comment: For the answer.